# Proper way to filter data from database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring framework so the questions might come up as silly.

I have a database with almost 5000 entries in it. I need to create a GET request which takes 5 parameters to filter the data. Depending on what parameters are present, the request will filter the data. I was able to do it but I don't think I am doing it efficiently. So here are my questions:

- First, Which one is a better approach? Retrieving all data from database using repository.findAll() and then using stream + filter to filter out the data **OR** writing the query in JPA repository interface and then simply calling those methods? Which one would be more efficient?
- Second, What is the best way to retrieve a huge amount of data? Like in my case, there are 5000 entries. So how should I retrieve them? I've read something about Pageable but not 100% sure. Is that the way to go or is there any other better option?

Any help appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: How many times will the GET endpoint be hit? Is there any other things that you want to do with the info, i.e., will you be using caching? Will you be presenting statistical data?

Comment: I'm still a novice, so don't know anything about caching and the GET endpoint will be hit probably 50-100 times a day.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question is better to retrieve only required records from DB, instead of retrieve all entries and then filter them on **Java** .Writing the query in JPA repository one of the options , but also you can use `CriteriaQuery` to do this . `CriteriaQuery` given you more manipulate on fillture items on programmatically way . Also it help you with your second question .

Yes **Pagination** is one of approach , special for Web Applications . The Main idea of pagination is to dividing large records of data to smaller chunks (**Pages**) , user search for his record on first chuck (Page) then he/she will request the a second page if he/she did found it .

Below example summarize your two queries . In this example am trying to retrive/search on large number of orders .

Bean *OrderSearchCriteria.java* , use to identify filter parameter .

```
public class OrderSearchCriteria {

private String user ; 

private Date periodFrom  ; 

private Date periodTo  ; 

private String status ;

private Integer  pageLimit ;

private Integer page ;

private Integer  offset ;

private String sortOrder ;

.....
}
```

Repository

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Integer> , JpaSpecificationExecutor<Order>{}
```

Below using CriteriaQuery to filter orders based on submitted criteria .

```
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService{
......
@Override
public Page<Order> orderSearch(OrderSearchCriteria orderSearchCriteria) {
    if (orderSearchCriteria.getPage() == null)
        orderSearchCriteria.setPage(orderSearchCriteria.getOffset() / orderSearchCriteria.getPageLimit());

    return  orderRepository.findAll(OrderSearchSpecificaton.orderSearch(orderSearchCriteria) , 
                                          PageRequest.of(orderSearchCriteria.getPage(), orderSearchCriteria.getPageLimit()));
}

private static class OrderSearchSpecificaton {

    public static Specification<Order> orderSearch(OrderSearchCriteria orderSearchCriteria) {
        return new Specification<Order>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Order> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(orderSearchCriteria.getUser()) && !orderSearchCriteria.getUser().toUpperCase().equals("ALL")) {
                    Join<Order, User> userJoin = root.join("user") ;
                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(userJoin.get("name") ,orderSearchCriteria.getUser()));
                }

                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(orderSearchCriteria.getStatus()) && !orderSearchCriteria.getStatus().toUpperCase().equals("ALL")) {
                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("status") ,orderSearchCriteria.getStatus()));
                }

                if (orderSearchCriteria.getPeriodFrom() != null) {
                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("entryDate"), orderSearchCriteria.getPeriodFrom())) ;
                }


                if (orderSearchCriteria.getPeriodTo()!= null) {
                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThan(root.get("entryDate"), orderSearchCriteria.getPeriodTo())) ;
                }

                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(orderSearchCriteria.getSortOrder())) {
                    if (orderSearchCriteria.getSortOrder().toUpperCase().equals("DESC")) {
                        query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get("entryDate"))) ;
                    }

                    else {
                        query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get("entryDate"))) ;
                    }
                }

                return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
            }

        };
   }

}
```

Call `orderSearch` from Controller

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(path = "/order/search" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public HashMap<String, Object> orderSearch(@RequestBody OrderSearchCriteria orderSearchCriteria) {
    Page<Order> page = getOrderService().orderSearch(orderSearchCriteria) ;
    HashMap<String, Object>  result = new HashMap<>() ;
    result.put("total", page.getTotalElements());
    result.put("rows", page.getContent());
    return result ;
}
```

I hope this can help you .

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I will look into detail about CriteriaQuery and how it works. But what about if no parameter is passed in the request? Then I've to return all the data. How should I manage that? I don't think returning 5000 entries at once is a good idea.

Comment: You have the two paramters `page` and `pageLimit` to control this . `pageLimit` is number or records on one page , for example when you set `pageLimit=10` and `page=0` , user will get first 10 records of 5000 entries and can get the next 10 records by increase the `page` value

Answer (score 1):

What is *better* depends on context. Only *you* know what is better *in your context*. Nevertheless I'd suggest you to consider following solution.

1) Use **Spring Data JPA Specifications**

You say that some of 5 parameters can be present, some not. I'd suggest you to use *Spring Data JPA Specifications*. Here is a good [article and examples](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).

The idea is following. For each of your 5 parameters you create a specification. In this example these are methods *customerHasBirthday()* and *isLongTermCustomer()* in the class *CustomerSpecifications*.

Then you create a query dynamically, depending on what parameters are present:

```
if (parameter1 is present){
    add specification 1 to the "where" clause
}
...
if (parameter5 is present){
    add specification 5 to the "where" clause
}
```

Then calls *findAll()* using the resulting aggregated specification.

Of course other solutions are possible: You can build a JPQL Query as a string dynamically, depending on what parameters are present. Or you can dynamically build a native SQL query. But *specifications* have one more advantage: pageable queries in Spring accept only *specifications*.

2) Use **Paging**

If your application has only 2-3 users that send only a few requests per hour, then loading 5000 items per request *might* work well. But if *all* the results need to be rendered in browser, this can take a lot of resources on the client and can be a performance problem.

If you have more users that send more requests, then also on the server side CPU and RAM can be insufficient and you can face performance problems and, as a consequence, very long response time for users.

That's why I'd suggest you to use *Paging*. You can limit the number of elements in the response. Suppose you set page size to 100. Then each request will need less resources:

- On database level: Instead of 5000 database will return only 100 elements, it will be better performance
- Application will create from JDBC response only 100 Java objects instead of 5000 -> less memory and less CPU used
- Application will have less overhead with converting Java objects to JSON, again less memory and less CPU
- The response time will be better, because sending of 100 elements from application to the user takes less time than sending 5000 elements
- Browser performance *can* be better. It depends on the client logic. In case client application is not smart and renders *every* response element, this will be a higher performance, because rendering of 100 elements will be faster than rendering of 5000 elements.

There are many tutorials about paging, do one or two that you like.

Comment: Thanks man! I'll look into the link (y)

Comment: @BhaveshMisri: If you find it helpful, you can vote it up.